# I don't know there is needed subject

Tags: subjects

Recently, I read on the reddit sentence: "Grinned from ear to ear when I heard it". I would like to ask why there is no subject at the beginning of "I". Is this something acceptable, is it normal for colloquial language? I understand the sentence, but the subject is missing, in my opinion.

Comment: It's normal for informal written language, for example in a diary. _Monday. Went shopping, bought a new dress._

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable. Yes, it is normal for colloquial language. And you yourself have supplied proof that it is. More information in the linked question, which I'm closing this one as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1):

Native speakers often leave the subject *implied* if it's clear from the context of the sentence who is acting. That happens often in colloquial writing/speech and occasionally in formal speech.

Like all things with language, whether it's "wrong" or not depends on your audience and whether your meaning is clearly expressed. For a social website like Reddit, the sentence is fine, but you wouldn't want to write such a sentence for a formal report at your workplace.